# Totaling Three Columns for a Balance Column in a SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list

Newish to SharePoint so, hopefully, I am explaining this clearly.

I want to build a simple Timesheet List where I have the following columns:

- **Employee Name** (Choice column, drop down of employee names)
- **Vacation Start** (Number column, is the number of total vacation hours
  a specific employee has)
- **Vacation Taken** (Number column, is the number of vacation hours a specific employee has taken)
- **Vacation Earned** (Number column, is the number of vacation hours a specific employee has earned per month)

I realize I can total these columns these by going to Modify View then the "Total" section in the list setting. And filtering by employee name...

But, what I also want is a column called **Vacation Balance** that would add all the total earned days (*Vacation Earned*) to the Vacation Start column then subtract all the total *Vacation Taken* days for each specific employee.

Example. 
Employee Alen has 
Vacation Start = 100
Vacation Earned = 8
Vacation Taken = 40

So therefore Vacation Balance would be 68 for Alen.

I tried a calculated column with *=(Vacation Start + Vacation Earned)- Vacation Taken* but the variable always shows a -variable for whatever shows in Vacation Taken.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it shows -68 instead of 68? Can you also provide a screenshot of your formula? I have taken 3 columns of number types and created a calculated column with your formula It works fine.

Comment: =SUM([Vac Start]+[Vac Earned])-SUM([Vac Taken])

Comment: In the actual columns- For Vac Balance-- For the first entry, Vacation Start = 119 so Vacation Balance = 119 but when the second entry occurred Vacation Taken = 8 then the Vac Balance was -8. Third entry, no vacation was taken so Vacation Balance = 0. Then for the fourth entry, I entered 8 hours of Vacation Taken so that Vacation Balance = -8 (again).

Comment: This is my formula `=([Vacation Start]+[Vacation Earned])-[Vacation Spent]`. Try this it should work

Comment: It's still giving me the Vacation Balance number as a negative number in Vacation Balance. =([Vac Start]+[Vac Earned])-[Vac Taken]

Comment: I just tested and working as expected if you remove SUM in the formula.

Comment: Example: First entry Vacation Start = 119 thus Vacation Balance = 119.  Enter 2nd entry of 8 hours of Vacation Taken, Vacation Balance now equals -8.

Comment: I don't have sum in the formula. All columns are number columns, save Vacation Balance which is calculated column with the =([Vac Start]+[Vac Earned])-[Vac Taken] formula being used.

Comment: Are the type of columns is "Number"?

Comment: I went in and edited the second entry (Vacation Taken = 8) and added 119 on the Vacation Start and now the formula works... Vacation Balance = 111. I guess I have to figure out now how to have Vacation Start stay as a constant each time the list is update. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the column formula and add again by selecting columns from the right side columns panel. Should be an issue with Vacation Earned internal columns. Also, check the Vacation Earned field settings also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the formula as below mentioned.

```
=([Vac Start]+[Vac Earned])-[Vac Taken]
```